# Запрос на выборку

Tags: sql

Добрый утро, пожалуйста, помогите составить SQL-запрос на выборку из такой базы данных информации только о тех покупателях, которые купили один и тот же товар более 3х раз. Мои попытки заканчиваются фейлами :( 

`SELECT CUSTOMERS.COMPANYNAME 
FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERID IN (
    SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE COUNT(CUSTOMERID)>3)`

---

[image: 123]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS.COMPANYNAME 
  FROM CUSTOMERS 
 WHERE CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERID IN ( SELECT customerID 
                                   FROM ORDERS 
`                                 group by customerid
                                 having COUNT(*)>3)
```

Вроде так

Comment: Да. Спасибо. Туплю уже после ночи:)

Comment: Подзапрос скорее `select a.CUSTOMERID from ORDERS a inner join ORDER_DETAILS b on a.ORDERID = b.ORDERID group by a.CUSTOMERID, b.PRODUCTID having COUNT(*) > 3`. Лыжи с яблоками считать отдельно.

Comment: доп. вопрос:
как найти категорию, в которой половина товаров была куплена хотя бы 1 раз?

Comment: Половина от чего? От всей номенклатуры товаров или от чего-то другого?

Comment: Да, от всего списка товаров в категории

Answer (score 1):

Если не наврал, то:

```
select a.CATEGORYID
 from
   (select CATEGORYID, count(*) as CNT 
      from PRODUCTS group by CATEGORYID) a
   inner join
   (select CATEGORYID, count(*) as CNT 
      from PRODUCTS where PRODUCTID
         in (select distinct PRODUCTID from ORDER_DETAILS)
      group by CATEGORYID) b
   on a.CATEGORYID = b.CATEGORYID
 having a.CNT <= b.CNT * 2
```

Первый подзапрос -- общее кол-во товаров в категории, второй -- товары, по которым есть ORDER. Те товары, по которым нет продаж отсеются ещё join'ом

**Поправлено. Добавлена группировка во втором подзапросе.**

Comment: спасибо! чуть позже проверю